# How can I repair the carpet around a new shower?

Tags: bathroom, carpet

I just had a new shower put in, and the existing carpet doesn't quite go close enough to the bottom of the shower.  It looks uneven.  Is there something I can buy to make it flush?

Comment: Carpeting in the bathroom? That's a breeding ground for mold/mildew, and a great path to get water into the subfloor where it will rot. You want something waterproof like tile or vinyl.

Comment: My grandparent's home had shag carpeting in one of the bathrooms ... it was the bathroom off the kitchen, even though it had a full tub/shower, and I never knew anyone to use the tub for anything other than hanging up wet coats in it, though.

Comment: A picture would help, as well as telling us exactly how far "not quite close enough" is.

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the fact that carpet in a bathroom is just a bad idea, I see two options:

1. Install a threshold to cover the gap 
   [image: Threshold]
   <sub>(source: [abbey-carpets.co.uk](http://www.abbey-carpets.co.uk/shopimages/products/normal/8mm-zbar-l.jpg))</sub>
2. You might be able to put down a new tack strip and stretch the carpet.  This will really depend on how large the gap is (you didn't say)

[image: Tack strip]
<sub>(source: [homedepot.ca](https://www.homedepot.ca/wcsstore/HomeDepotCanada/images/catalog/16037.20-461Image_4.jpg))</sub>